# How to rotate a bounding box at any angle in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I felt confused to crop an image along any angle, i.e. pi/4, how can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to crop rotated bounding box.

The example doesn't show how to select the bounding box, and the angle (user interface is excluded).

For keeping the example simple, the bounding box parameters are: center, size and angle (instead of 4 corners).
Center is kept in place, when rotating.
Size is the width and height of destination crop area (size after rotation).

In case you need to calculate corners transformation, you can use rotation matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Code sample:

```
%Bounding box parameters: center, width, height and angle.
%Center is selected, because center is kept the same when rotating.
center_x = 256; %Center column index (applied center is 256.5)
center_y = 192; %Center row index (applied center is 192.5)
width = 300;  %Number of columns of destination (cropped) area (even integer)
height = 200; %Number of rows of destination (cropped) area (even integer)
phi = 120; %Rotation angle in degrees

%Read sample image.
I = imread('peppers.png');

%Add center cross, for verifying center is kept. 
I(center_y-1:center_y, center_x-30:center_x+30, :) = 255;
I(center_y-30:center_y+30, center_x-1:center_x, :) = 255;

%Rotate the entire input image, dimensions of J will be the same as I.
J = imrotate(I, phi, 'bicubic', 'crop');

%Crop rectangular are with size width by height around center_x, center_y from J.
C = J(center_y-height/2+1:center_y+height/2, center_x-width/2+1:center_x+width/2, :);

%Display result:
figure;imshow(C);
```

Result:
[image]